# creating a video database

Tags: database, video-streaming, html5-video

I am interested in creating a video databse. My goal is to have a folder where my videos will be kept and each time I copy/delete a video the website that presents them should be updated to. the problem is I have no idea how to approach it.
**Should I..**

1. Use Sql and store a reference to each video location?
2. Have a script that checks all the time if new changes happen in that folder?
3. A package like joomla?

I am using ubuntu btw. I already have a simple html5 page, and I am presenting the videos using html5 video.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size and the performance you want.

1.Way : use php to scan the folder and generate links on the fly

2.way : Use a database to store the file names and retrieve the names from the database and generate urls

pros and cons.

1. simple to implement , no changes in upload or download script. no database required.
2. You need have a database , little coding required for upload and also while genrating a page

Answer (score 0):

You should make a db (format does not matter) and storing in it only file names of videos: the videos would be stored on hard drive.

Any operation on the web site will pass first on db for insert/update/delete videos records and then (maybe in a transaction context) on the file system.

This would be the standard approach to your question.